# in linux what are ls flags in sftp

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sftp

in linux, we have lots of flags to list files in command  ls. we can't do the same inside sftp commannd. For example, in linux, I can list a file's full time by runnling command: 
`ls --full-time filename`
when I sftp to a server, I can't run command: ls --full-time.

The ls help in sftp doesn't list all available flags. So can you please tell me what are ls flags in sftp?

Thank you!

Comment: `ls` in `sftp`(an internal (s)ftp command) is very different from `ls` command on Linux/POSIX. Please do not confuse the two even if they have the same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ls` command in `sftp` is an internal `sftp` command which is in no way related to the `ls` command of the remote system's core utilites.

`sftp` (which has a similar interface as `ftp`) provides it's internal commands to allow listing of files(among other commands), which does not invoke the `ls` of the core utilities. So do not expect the same behavior.

For more details on `sftp`'s internal commands please refer to [sftp manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp) or [this page](http://kb.iu.edu/data/akqg.html)